# How do I print specific items from a python list?

Tags: python, list

I am trying to print multiple items from a list in Python. I have looked at many examples but I am unable to get them to work. What is a good way to print items from the imported list based on their list index.

The commented out example in my code is what I thought will work and cant find a simple solution.

```
items = []

with open('input.txt') as input_file:
    for line in input_file:
        items.append(line)

print(items[5],items[6])
#print(items[5,6,7]
```

Comment: If for some reason you don't want to use the built-in `operator.itemgetter`, you can  get all the values with a simple list comprehension: `[item[i] for i in indices]`

Comment: indices is not defined.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it would be with a for loop.

```
item_list = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','i']  # an example list.
index_to_print = [5,6,7]  # add all index you want to print to this list.

for i in item_list:
    if item_list.index(i) in index_to_print:
        print(i)
```

**update:** instead of looping through the whole item_list, we can loop through the indexes you want to print.

```
for i in index_to_print:
    if i < len(item_list):
        print(item_list[i])
    else:
        print('given index is out of range.')
```

Comment: This is bad for several reasons. It won't find duplicates in the list  (try changing the `'i'` to an `'a'` in your example). It also needlessly iterates through the list for every item in the list. That's O(n^2).

Comment: "What is a good way to print items from the imported list based on their list index." I am assuming that he already know the indexes of items he want to print. In that case there is no need to check for duplicates, right?. It do iterate through the whole list. I didn't think about that.

Comment: so that works but if I have [8,2,4] in the index_to_print it will print them in the order of [2,4,8], is there any way that it will print them out in the order I request?

Comment: I updated the answer considering what was noted by Mark. try now